# How to use loaderInfo?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, programming-languages, loading

I want to make a loading bar but at first I need to have loading info per enter frame. This is how I do it but it seem not working. Could you teach me how to do it?

```
 var mapLoader : Loader = new Loader( );
     var mapLoaderInfoLoad:Number;
     var mapLoaderInfoTotal:Number;

public function engine() 
{

        addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame,false,0,true );

        mapLoader.load( new URLRequest( "Mapcontrol.swf" ) );
        mapLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );

}
private function onEnterFrame( evt:Event ):void
    {mapLoaderInfoLoad = mapLoader.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
        mapLoaderInfoTotal = mapLoader.loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
        trace(mapLoaderInfoLoad);
        trace(mapLoaderInfoTotal);}

public function completeHandler ( eventOBJ : Event ) : void
     {
         stage.addChild( mapLoader.content );
     }
```

Comment: and the purpose of these code is to show the percentage of loading when mapLoader is loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bytesTotal of a Loader's loaderInfo will return 0 until the Loader has fired it's first `progress` event.  Is there a reason why you want to use an enterFrame in this way rather than the progress event?

**Simple Progress Event Example:**

```
var mapLoader : Loader = new Loader();
var mapLoaderInfoLoad:Number;
var mapLoaderInfoTotal:Number;

public function engine() 
{
    mapLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );
    mapLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
    mapLoader.load( new URLRequest( "Mapcontrol.swf" ) );  
}

private function progressHandler(evt:ProgressEvent):void
{
    mapLoaderInfoLoad = evt.bytesLoaded;
    mapLoaderInfoTotal = evt.bytesTotal;
    trace(mapLoaderInfoLoad);
    trace(mapLoaderInfoTotal);
}
```

---

**Enter Frame**

Of course, there might be a reason for you to use an enterFrame event.  You could still do so as in your example, but let the progressHandler from my example populate your variables; or wait until the first progress event is fired, then delete the progress event listener and add your enterFrame listener instead.  As long as you don't try to read `mapLoader.loaderInfo.bytesTotal` before the first progress event is fired you should be OK.

Answer (score 4):

you could just use the PROGRESS event:

```
mapLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
// ...
private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
  trace("Downloaded " + event.bytesLoaded + " out of " + event.bytesTotal + " bytes");
}
```

Comment: Thx you a lot ^^ I just didn't know the existence of progressEvent until now. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
stop();
var mapLoader : Loader = new Loader( );
function engine():void {    

    mapLoader.load( new URLRequest( "index.swf" ) );
    mapLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );
    mapLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressAction);    
}
function onProgressAction (e:ProgressEvent):void 
{
    var loaded:Number = e.target.bytesLoaded;
    var total:Number = e.target.bytesTotal;
    var percent:Number(loaded/total) * 100;
}    
function completeHandler( eventOBJ : Event ):void    {
    stage.addChild( eventOBJ.target.content );
    mapLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressAction);  
}
engine();
```

This will works

Comment: Why are you returning the data from the stage loaderInfo object rather than from the active loader?

Comment: @shanethehat : Okay.. I 've changed and I am sry. May I know whats the wrong in using stage?

Comment: using stage for the target of an enterFrame event is fine, no problem there.  The problem is that in the enterFrame handler, `e.target` is the target of the handler, not the loader that is active.  He needs to check `mapLoader.loaderInfo`, not the target of the event handler, whatever that may be.

Comment: Yes, removed now it's fixed :)